# virtualbox cannot detect usb flash drive on a linux host

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have linux operating system and i installed virtualbox on it. The problem is when i insert a usb to my computer, the linux os detects it but not in the virtualbox. Does anyone knows how to fix this? thanks.

Comment: The answer to this question can be easily found by googling around. It goes to show you have made no effort whatsoever to solve the problem yourself. Showing that you have already made some attempts, and telling the forum where you failed, is a much better recipe for life in general, for working with pcs, and more specifically to get a moderately knowledgeable answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I googled it and found a solution at stackoverflow. Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021300/usb-devices-are-not-recognized-in-virtualbox-linux-host.

I tried the procedure and it works fine for me. Thanks.